# Touch to hide tool bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uitoolbar, uitouch

I want to hide and show tool bar when touch in The area  **CGRectMake(130, 0, 60, 480)**

without using **UIGestureRecognizer** because its effect my other views

if touch once in the area , tool bar should hide and if tool bar is hidden , should show the tool bar

i have tried this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
    if (mainToolbar.hidden == YES) {
        mainToolbar.hidden=NO;
    }
  else if(mainToolbar.hidden == NO){
           [mainToolbar setHidden:YES];
    }
  }
```

but its hide tool bar when touch in to tool bar only

thanks......

Comment: Where did you put this code ? Did you subclass your toolbar ?

Comment: yes i have taken tool bar from subclass

Comment: then the touchBegan method will have effect only in the toolbar. In other words, it will work only if the user touch the toolbar.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use UIGestureRecognizer, "because its effect my other views" isn't quite a reason

Comment: If i use UIGestureRecognizer my pages are not scroll properly

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in the view where you added tool bar.  You will get location of touch using this code:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: touch.view];
```

And then check if touch is inside your rect using `CGRectContainsPoint:` function.

Another approach is simply put an button on the required area.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The method gives you an NSSet of all touches on the screen.  You can use this to customize your behavior for touches.  For example:

```
//This will change the state of whether mainToolbar is hidden or not.  In the case of multiple touches, it will change the property if any touch is in the CGRect area.
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGRect testRect = CGRectMake(130, 0, 60, 480);
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(testRect, [touch locationInView:self.view])) {
            mainToolbar.hidden = !mainToolbar.hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you only want the action to happen if one touch is made and ignore it if the user is touching with multiple fingers, you would check for that:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGRect testRect = CGRectMake(130, 0, 60, 480);
    if ([touches count] == 1) {
        //If there is only one touch, we check for that.  Otherwise, we ignore it.
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(testRect, [touch locationInView:self.view])) {
            mainToolbar.hidden = !mainToolbar.hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

You can do some really cool things with just the four functions `touchesBegan:` `touchesMoved:` `touchesEnded:` and `touchesCanceled:`.